# C++: Copying an element from an unordered_set to a vector

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-set

Background: I am implementing the nearest neighbor algorithm for the Traveling-Salesman-Problem. I need to calculate the distance traveled for the tour as well as keep track of the order of points visited. I have defined a point class with instance variables `x` and `y` and a function `calcDist` for calculating the distance between two points. I start by storing all of the points in a `std::unordered_set` named `points`, creating an empty `std::vector` named `path` to store the tour path, and assigning the starting point to `startPoint`, and pass these to my `nearestNeighbor()` function:

```
void nearestNeighbor(unordered_set<Point, PointHasher> points, vector<Point> &path, Point startPoint) {
  // Declare variables
  unordered_set<Point, PointHasher>::iterator it;
  Point currentLocation, possibleNeighbor, nearestNeighbor;
  double totalDist = 0;
  int pointsCount = path.capacity() - 1;

  // Set the starting location
  it = points.find(startPoint);
  currentLocation = *it;
  path[0] = currentLocation;
  points.erase(currentLocation);
  cout << "Start location: " << path[0].x << ", " << path[0].y << endl;

  // Create the path
  for (int i = 1; points.size() > 0; i++) {
    double minDist = -1;
    // Find the current location's nearest neighbor
    for (it = points.begin(); it != points.end(); it++) {
      possibleNeighbor = *it;
      int currentDist = currentLocation.calcDist(possibleNeighbor);
      if (minDist == -1 || currentDist < minDist) {
        minDist = currentDist;
        nearestNeighbor = possibleNeighbor;
      }
    }
    // Record nearest neighbor data and prepare for the next iteration
    currentLocation = nearestNeighbor;
    path[i] = currentLocation;
    points.erase(currentLocation);
    totalDist += minDist;
    cout << "Nearest neighbor: " << path[i].x << ", " << path[i].y << endl;
  }
  // Return to the starting location
  path[pointsCount] = startPoint;
  cout << "End location: " << startPoint.x << ", " << startPoint.y << endl;
  cout << "Path:" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
    cout << path[0].x << ", " << path[0].y << endl;
  }
  cout << "Total distance: " << totalDist << endl;
}
```

The problem is that once the program exits the outer for loop, all the points in `path` are overwritten somehow. To see what I mean, here is the output:

```
Start location: 3, 4
Nearest neighbor: 6, 8
Nearest neighbor: 11, 7
Nearest neighbor: 50, 8
End location: 3, 4
Path:
3, 4
3, 4
3, 4
3, 4
3, 4
Total distance: 49
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I am thinking this either has to be a problem with pointers/addresses of the vector elements, or something with scope since the problem happens after exiting the for loop. I have even tried printing the `path[1]` after each iteration to see when it gets changed, but it is correct throughout the loop, and only changes in the output at the end. Any thoughts? I am stumped. And if you have made it this far, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Your first parameter is passed by value.  Were you expecting `points` to retain the changes you made inside of that function?  Well, they won't stick due to `points` being passed by value.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't think he needs `points` to change, passing that by value is fine (although maybe slower than by reference). He's already passing `path` by reference, so that should be changed.

Comment: Haha yes without context this is confusing. I pass `points` by value because I will be running other TSP algorithms on it as well. I pass `path` by reference because I will later be timing the algorithm, so I want to output the contents of `path` outside the function call, although now that I think about it, I could just as easily leave it in the function but after stopping a timer. So yea, hope that makes sense, and thanks guys for your input. If you have further critiques I would be happy to hear them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are always outputing the coordinates of path[0] man

```
for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
    cout << path[0].x << ", " << path[0].y << endl;
}
```

Comment: Fixed it, works fine now. I feel so unbelievably stupid. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
    cout << path[0].x << ", " << path[0].y << endl;
  }
```

This doesn't iterate through `i`. Change your 0 to `i` and you'll likely see something more helpful:

```
for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
    cout << path[i].x << ", " << path[i].y << endl;
}
```

Edit: Change `path[i] = currentLocation;` to `path.push_back(currentLocation);` - this will automatically increase the size of your `path` vector to fit the new elements.

```
void nearestNeighbor(
    unordered_set<Point, PointHasher> points,
    vector<Point> &path,
    Point startPoint,
    double &totalDist) // note the new variable passed here
{
  // Declare variables
  unordered_set<Point, PointHasher>::iterator it;
  Point currentLocation, possibleNeighbor, nearestNeighbor;
  // double totalDist = 0; Remove this line
  // int pointsCount = path.capacity() - 1; And this

  // Set the starting location
  it = points.find(startPoint);
  currentLocation = *it;
  path.push_back(currentLocation); // Changed this line
  points.erase(currentLocation);
  cout << "Start location: " << path[0].x << ", " << path[0].y << endl;

  // Create the path
  for (int i = 1; points.size() > 0; i++) {
    double minDist = -1;
    // Find the current location's nearest neighbor
    for (it = points.begin(); it != points.end(); it++) {
      possibleNeighbor = *it;
      int currentDist = currentLocation.calcDist(possibleNeighbor);
      if (minDist == -1 || currentDist < minDist) {
        minDist = currentDist;
        nearestNeighbor = possibleNeighbor;
      }
    }
    // Record nearest neighbor data and prepare for the next iteration
    currentLocation = nearestNeighbor;
    path.push_back(currentLocation); // And this line
    points.erase(currentLocation);
    totalDist += minDist;
    cout << "Nearest neighbor: " << path[i].x << ", " << path[i].y << endl;
  }
  // Return to the starting location
  path.push_back(startPoint); // And here also!
  cout << "End location: " << startPoint.x << ", " << startPoint.y << endl; // This I didn't change, 
// but perhaps you should make it reflect the last point in the vector, 
// not the start point which is supposed to be the last point in the vector
  cout << "Path:" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
    cout << path[i].x << ", " << path[i].y << endl;
  }
  cout << "Total distance: " << totalDist << endl;
}
```

Comment: Again, thanks chris for your help. As you and others have pointed out, the problem was that I was outputting the wrong thing. I feel very dumb haha. Also, I don't use push_back because I set the capacity of `path` in main with `vector<Point> path(points.size() + 1);` In theory it should be faster although I'm sure it's negligible. Also very possible I don't know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any place which grows the size of the `path` vector.

I suspect that you're passing an empty std::vector, for the second argument, and as soon as you hit `path[0]=currentLocation;` ... undefined behavior.

Also, I don't think that capacity() does what you think it does.

That, and, as others have pointed out, you're not outputing the contents of the array correctly, but that's a minor problem. The major problem here is that this program is likely scribbling over and corrupting the heap.

Comment: Ah yes I think I understand what you're saying. I actually didn't mention it in my question but I do set the capacity of `path` in main using `vector<Point> path(points.size() + 1);` But you're right, the problem was that I outputted the contents of the array incorrectly. Thanks for your help...I feel very dumb.

Comment: capacity() is not the same thing as size(). If you use capacity() to figure out how many elements you can put in the container, eventually you will end up hitting uninitialized memory, resulting in undefined behavior.